# fs.readFile can't read file paths on windows, wrong encoding?

Tags: node.js, windows, encoding, electron, readfile

I'm passing the string "C:\random-folder\ui-debug.log" file path to fs.readFile() on a virtualized Windows 11 installation under macos and a x64 bit electron installation and nodeJS 18 (idk if that matters).

Using the following code:

```
const filepath = path.resolve(path.normalize(pathStr))
const file = fs.readFileSync(filepath)
```

but continuously get this error:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_VALUE]: The argument 'path' must be a string or Uint8Array without null bytes. Received 'C:\\random-folder\\ui-debug.log\x00'
```

The file path always seems to be interpreted incorrectly by readFileSync, the **\x00** is always added to the end of the path it errors with. This same code works fine on macos.

What is the correct way to read arbitrary file paths with nodejs/electron under Windows? Thanks!

Comment: What is `pathStr`?

Comment: You should use forward slashes `/`

Comment: Remove the  `0` from the end of the string.  That's not a valid character in a windows path.

Comment: What is the source of the data in `pathStr`?  Can you show us that code?  Perhaps you can do something different upstream from this code so that you have a valid string (without null characters in it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was to do with how the string was being parsed in the first place. Before passing the filepath to readFileSync, it was being converted to ucs2

```
const pathStr = clipboard.readBuffer('FileNameW').toString('ucs2')
```

On windows some extra characters were added at the end of the string but was console logged as normal (some internal conversion going on?) so it looked like a normal path in console but internally it had some extra encoded characters on the end.

I solved it with some regex:

```
const pathStr = clipboard.readBuffer('FileNameW').toString('ucs2').replace(RegExp(String.fromCharCode(0), 'g'), '')
```

Now readFileSync reads the file just fine!